# Creating a database error in installing autoresponder program

Tags: php, database, error-handling

Installed autoresponder program in php but when running it I get the following error.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bft_smails` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `sender`
varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', `receiver` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', `subject` varchar(255)
NOT NULL default '', `message` text NOT NULL, `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',  `mailtype` varchar(10) default NULL, `read` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `sent`
int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `track` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`list_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) TYPE=MyISAM:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 14

I am new to databases and php.
Any help would be appreciated.

I don't know how to proceed.